# Is it at all possible to erase from a vector with C++11's for loops?

Tags: c++, c++11, for-loop, vector, erase

Alright. For the sake of other (more simple but not explanatory enough) questions that this might look like, I am not asking if this is possible or impossible (because I found that out already), I am asking if there is a lighter alternative to my question.

What I have is what would be considered a main class, and in that main class, there is a variable that references to a 'World Map' class. In essence, this 'WorldMap' class is a container of other class variables. The main class does all of the looping and updates all of the respective objects that are active. There are times in this loop that I need to delete an object of a vector that is deep inside a recursive set of containers (As shown in the code provided). It would be extremely tedious to repeatedly have to reference the necessary variable as a pointer to another pointer (and so on) to point to the specific object I need, and later erase it (this was the concept I used before switching to C++11) so instead I have a range for loop (also shown in the code). My example code shows the idea that I have in place, where I want to cut down on the tedium as well as make the code a lot more readable.

This is the example code:

```
struct item{
    int stat;
};

struct character{
    int otherStat;
    std::vector<item> myItems;
};

struct charContainer{
    std::map<int, character> myChars;
};

int main(){
    //...
    charContainer box;
    //I want to do something closer to this
    for(item targItem: box.myChars[iter].myItems){
        //Then I only have to use targItem as the reference
        if(targItem.isFinished)
            box.myChars[iter].myItems.erase(targItem);
    }
    //Instead of doing this
    for(int a=0;a<box.myChars[iter].myItems.size();a++){
        //Then I have to repeatedly use box.myChars[iter].myItems[a]
        if(box.myChars[iter].myItems[a].isFinished)
            box.myChars[iter].myItems.erase(box.myChars[iter].myItems[a]);
    }
}
```

TLDR: I want to remove the tedium of repeatedly calling the full reference by using the new range for loops shown in C++11.

**EDIT**: I am not trying to delete the elements all at once. I am asking how I would delete them in the matter of the first loop. I am deleting them when I am done with them externally (via an if statement). How would I delete specific elements, NOT all of them?

Comment: If I did that then there is a good chance someone will walk in and say: "I don't know what you're asking or attempting!"

Comment: Well, you can be clear about what you're asking without padding that doesn't change the nature answer (like your structs) and information that's unactionable... it's a fine line, but I'd say err on the side of brevity. In other words: A short question may get you some requests for clarification, while a long question may just get ignored to death.

Comment: This seems to get your attention pretty well :P. There is also a TLDR message if people want to cut to the chase right away. I am only formatting in such a way according to past experience.

Comment: Neither of your `for` statements make sense. Is there some condition that needs to be satisfied before you erase an element? As written, it looks like you're erasing every single one. Also, `vector::erase` takes iterator(s) to the item(s) to erase, not the items themselves. And I agree with Kerrek, you have way too much extraneous stuff in your question. The wall of text at the top is more likely to dissuade people from looking any further.

Comment: @Praetorian The condition for removing the element was not included because it was not necessary to the question. I am asking how I would delete it, not when.

Comment: So a wall of text is pertinent, but the actual code indicating what you want to do is not? The answer to your question in its current state is `vector::clear`. Anyway, since you seem hellbent on not following any advice, there's no point in further discussion. Best of luck.

Comment: I fixed my question where I am asking to delete SPECIFIC elements of a vector, NOT all of them.

Comment: @Molma Can you see the last part of my answer, and point out if there's anything else you need?

Comment: @Svalorzen If I am reading this correctly, then I am guessing that I can call `std::vector::erase()` after the for loop is done? With that guess, do I use the lambda inside the for loop? And will this work with the range for loop?

Comment: @Molma Comment under the answer if your questions are about the answer itself. But here there would be no loop at all, the `erase` and `remove_if` functions do all the work for you.

Comment: @Svalorzen Alright, thanks for the help, I will spend a bit to test this out. Also my apologies to the comment location, realized it afterward.

Comment: `//Instead of doing this` -- the code under that comment does not do what you think it does.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you simply want to clear an std::vector, there is a very simple method you can use:

```
std::vector<item> v;

// Fill v with elements...

v.clear(); // Removes all elements from v.
```

In addition to this, I'd like to point out that [1] to erase an element in a vector requires the usage of iterators, and [2] even if your approach was allowed, erasing elements from a vector inside a for loop is a bad idea if you are not careful. Suppose your vector has 5 elements:

```
std::vector<int> v = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
```

Then your loop would have the following effect:

- **First iteration:** `a == 0, size() == 5`. We remove the first element, then the vector will contain `{2, 3, 4, 5}`
- **Second iteration:** `a == 1, size() == 4`. We then remove the *second* element, then the vector will contain `{2,4,5}`
- **Third iteration:** `a == 2, size() == 3`. We remove the *third* element, and we are left with the final result `{2,4}`.

Since this does not actually empty the vector, I suppose it is not what you were looking for.

If instead you have some particular condition that you want to apply to remove the elements, it is very easily applied in C++11 in the following way:

```
std::vector<MyType> v = { /* initialize vector */ };

// The following is a lambda, which is a function you can store in a variable.
// Here we use it to represent the condition that should be used to remove
// elements from the vector v.
auto isToRemove = [](const MyType & value){ 
    return /* true if to remove, false if not */ 
};

// A vector can remove multiple elements at the same time using its method erase().
// Erase will remove all elements within a specified range. We use this method 
// together with another method provided by the standard library: remove_if.
// What it does is it deletes all elements for which a particular predicate 
// returns true within a range, and leaves the empty spaces at the end.
v.erase( std::remove_if( std::begin(v), std::end(v), isToRemove ), std::end(v) );

// Done!
```

Comment: A quick question: How would I go about breaking the erase loop? For example I have a loop where I am looking for something to move somewhere else (which is affected by other variables like distance and a cooldown), When I find that first occurrence that fits the description, `break` the loop.

Comment: That can be done with another standard library algorithm, `find_if`. You should probably read about all algorithms provided in the standard library though. You can find them here: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/

Answer (score 2):

> I am deleting them when I am done with them externally (via an if statement). How would I delete specific elements, NOT all of them?

In my opinion, you're looking at this the wrong way.  Writing loops to delete items from a sequence container is always problematic and not recommended.  Strive to stay away from removing items in this fashion.

When you work with containers, you should strategically set up your code so that you place the deleted or "about to be deleted" items in a part of the container that is easily accessed, away from the items in the container that you do not want to delete.  At the time you actually do want to remove them, you know where they are and thus can call some function to expel them from the container.

One answer was already given, and that is to use the `erase-remove(if)` idiom.  When you call `remove` or `remove_if`, the items that are "bad" are moved to the end of the container.  The return value for `remove(_if)` is the iterator to the start of the items that will be removed.  Then you feed this iterator to the `vector::erase` method to delete these items permanently from the container.

The other solution (but probably less used) is the `std::partition` algorithm.  The `std::partition` also can move the "bad" items to the end of the container, but unlike `remove(_if)`, the items are still valid (i.e. you can leave them at the end of the container and still use them safely).  Then later on, you can remove them as you wish in a separate step since `std::partition` also returns an iterator.

Comment: This is pretty interesting in a sense of if I was only deleting them on an if statement, but I am not. I have vectors placed all over the program that are randomly deleting elements because they are not useful anymore. This is also another of the situations I explained in my question's comments. There are other member functions and changes I do to the each iteration (for example: `targItem->function1(); targItem->function2();` etc) before checking if the iteration is "flagged for deletion", which was implied with the comments.

Comment: My program is already extremely large and adding every single bit of it would make many readers angry, which is the reason I gave an example. This code is nothing close to what actually happens but the main points of the question are written and other, not so important, calls to functions and such are commented, hence why confusion is common in my questions. I am also (hopefully temporarily) unable to type excessively due to personal issues but staying in bed is way too depressing for a summer vacation (avoiding TMI).

Comment: Well, your original code shows the following idiom: `1) Go through my vector.  2) If an item has a certain condition, do stuff to it, then remove it.`  That is the `remove_if/erase` idiom, or at least the `partition/erase` idiom, as explained by the answers given.

Comment: And my potential error lies in statement 2. What I am doing is: `1) Go through my vector. 2) Modify/update the item. 3) If the item has a certain condition, remove it.` Again this is pretty much my fault because I suck at making example code.

Comment: Looks like you want to modify the item, then check if it fits a certain condition before removing it.  If so, then that can be done by remove_if() or std::partition().

Answer (score 0):

Why not have a standard iterator iterating over a vector. That way you can delete the element by passing an iterator. Then .erase() will return the next available iterator. And if your next iterator is iterator::end() then your loop will exit.