# C++ error erasing element of vector of deque

Tags: c++, stl

I have the following code:

```
deque<int> assigned_g_col_ids;
vector < deque<int> > assigned_g(MAX_P);
deque<int>::iterator it;

int distribute_gifts(int collegue) {
int position = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < number_of_presents; i++) {
    if (present_preferences[collegue][i] && available_gifts[i] > 0) {
        assigned_gifts[i].push_back(collegue);
        available_gifts[i]--;
        return 1;
    } else if (present_preferences[collegue][i] && !(available_gifts[i] > 0) && visited_gifts[i] == 0) {        
        visited_gifts[i] = 1; 
        assigned_gift_collegues_ids = assigned_gifts[i];
        for (it = assigned_gift_collegues_ids.begin(); it != assigned_gift_collegues_ids.end(); it++) {
            if (distribute_gifts(*it)) {
                assigned_gifts[i].erase(assigned_gift_collegues_ids.begin());
                assigned_gifts[i].push_back(collegue);

                return 1;
            }
            position+=1;
        }
    }
}
return 0;
```

}

I'm getting memory error at `assigned_g[i].erase(assigned_g_col_ids.begin() + position);`

How can I erase the element pointed by `it` from the `deque` if the return value of `distribute_g(*it)` is 1?

Comment: More than likely, it is a case of erasing from a vector while iterating over the vector.  Doing things this way is error-prone, as removing items from a vector can invalidate iterators.  Instead, consider the `remove-if/erase` idiom.

Comment: `it++` is not a good idea. Not to mention is hard to track what is going on at all in this code. Or I am bad at reading...

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Sorry, but could you elaborate the remove-if/erase idiom because i'm not familiar with it? I don't know if this is right but I don't want to erase from the vector. I want to access the `deque` int that `vector`position and then, erase the element in the `deque`

Comment: Please see answer here:  You may want to use std::partition. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23769151/is-it-at-all-possible-to-erase-from-a-vector-with-c11s-for-loops/23769898#23769898  In general, you should try to stay away from writing "insertion and/or erasure" code in a sequence container as you're doing now.  Basically, you need to think in terms of algorithms, and not write procedural, loop-oriented code.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Will try to understand. Thanks

Comment: Erasing from a `deque` invalidates **all** iterators as stated by the [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque/erase)

Comment: @Csq but since I'm returning and don't need the iterator no more, is that still a problem?

Comment: @Favolas. Did not see the return at first. Anyway, your code is hard to read.

Comment: @Favolas -- Yes, it's still a problem. Suppose some other function calls `distribute_g`, which in turn calls `distribute_g` recursively. The inner `distribute_g` returns and doesn't use the iterator. However, the outer call `distribute_g` is still in the loop, and the iterator is now invalidated.

Comment: What's `available_gifts`? You haven't shown what it is. Is this yet another file scope ("global") variable?

Comment: @DavidHammen Yes it is. is declared like this available_gifts[3] where available_gifts[0]=1; available_gifts[1]=2;available_gifts[2]=3;

Comment: Don't do that. The same goes for your new variable `assigned_gift_collegues_ids`. You are using C± (C plus or minus), not C++. The switch from C to C++ requires a new way of thinking. While the two languages look rather similar, superficially, they are very different languages in how good programmers think while developing solutions.

Comment: This question is getting an ["XY problem"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) feel to it. You are asking "Can someone help me with the troubles I'm having doing Y?" when you should be asking "how do I do X?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of things wrong here. A minor problem: It's best to adopt the habit of using prefix rather than suffix autoincrement and autodecrement (e.g., `++it` rather than `it++`).

A much bigger problem is that you have declared `deque<int>::iterator it` as a file scope variable. You are using that variable in multiple contexts because your function `distribute_g` is recursive. Those recursive calls will do who knows what to that global  iterator. The iterator should be local to the `for` loop in which it is used.

A related problem is that the iterator is invalidated by calling `erase`. Your code is immediately returns after calling `erase`, so it would appear that this is safe. However, you are calling `distribute_g` recursively. You need to reset the iterator after that recursive call to `distribute`.

Finally, what is the rationale for the recursive calls?

**Update**
Your updated code is illegal (and so was your original code).

Here's the crux of your problem:

```
assigned_gift_collegues_ids = assigned_gifts[i];
...
assigned_gifts[i].erase(assigned_gift_collegues_ids.begin());
```

That assignment to `assigned_gift_collegues_ids` makes a copy of `assigned_gifts[i]`. The iterator returned by `assigned_gift_collegues_ids.begin()` points to the start of the contents of that copy. It is illegal to use this iterator as an argument to `assigned_gifts[i].erase()`.

You need to rethink your design and your use of file scope variables. This latter point is particularly so within the context of recursive functions.

Comment: Thanks for your explanations. The basic idea in the recursive calls is to find if any of those people that have that gift can be assigned to other gift. I've edited the question

Comment: Once again thaks for your explanations. I've managed to achieve what I was aiming substituting the code for `assigned_gifts[i].erase(assigned_gifts[i].begin() + position);`. `position` keeps  track of the position in the `deque` to be erased

Answer (score 1):

You make a **copy** of the deque in this statement:

`assigned_g_col_ids = assigned_g[i]`

and then you use the erase of the original deque with and iterator from the copy

`assigned_g[i].erase(assigned_g_col_ids.begin() + position);`

---

Your code is really hard to read. E.g. you should declare variables where you use them, not at the beginning of the code as globals! (And I did not spot the recursive call either. As pointed out by David Hammen, do not use global variables as locals in recursive functions! And in any function!)

Also, using the standard algorithms as suggested in the comments can improve readability.

And I still do not understand what your code is trying to do.